# TypeError: b'1' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, http-post

I am trying to send a POST request as JSON.

*email variable is of type "bytes"

```
def request_to_SEND(email, index):
    url = "....."
    data = {
        "body": email.decode('utf-8'),
        "query_id": index,
        "debug": 1,
        "client_id": "1",
        "campaign_id": 1,
        "meta": {"content_type": "mime"}
    }
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        sys.exit()

    return response
```

I get the error:

```
 File "C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: b'1' is not JSON serializable
```

Could you please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us something we can reproduce? I put `"Hello"` in `email` and `0` in `index`, then copy-pasted the definition of `data`, and `json.dumps(data)` worked just fine.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is happening because you're passing a `bytes` object in the `data` dict (`b'1'`, specifically), probably as the value of `index`. You need to decode it to a `str` object before `json.dumps` can work with it:

```
data = {
    "body": email.decode('utf-8'),
    "query_id": index.decode('utf-8'),  # decode it here
    "debug": 1,
    "client_id": "1",
    "campaign_id": 1,
    "meta": {"content_type": "mime"}
}
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda

Comment: my data is of type bit, when i store it in a session and print session i m getting this   !!! @dano .

Comment: to avoid `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'` error `email.decode('utf-8') if email != None else email`

Comment: @dano: It worked for  me as well  when I get an error while retrive images from odoo db. I used rec.image.decode('utf-8'). Solved my TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable - - - . Thank you