# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Tags: python, json

I totally new in Python and stuck with this error:

I am trying to encode an image and then convert it to json to upload into a no-sql db. But when I am trying to convert it to json I am getting this error:

"AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '**dict**'"

Below is my python code:

```
import base64  
import json



def jsonDefault(object):
    return object.__dict__


with open("img123.png", "rb") as imageFile:  
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())  
    print(str)  
json_str = {'file_name':'img123','img_str':str}  
pytojson = json.dumps(json_str, default=jsonDefault)  
print(pytojson)
```

Comment: What is your `jsonDefault` function supposed to do?

Comment: jsonDefault is used to make it JSON Serialized as earlier I was getting that error when using json.dumps(json_str).

Comment: You can't encapsulates a _**binary**_Object into `json` Object`. [Edit] your Question and explain why you would want to do that.

Comment: Hi @Kuntal if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are trying to access a property that a `bytes` object doesn't have (`__dict__`). I understand that you need to return a format that can be serialized to JSON.

This works for me, but I don't know if it's the decoding you desire:

```
def jsonDefault(o):
    return o.decode('utf-8')
```

See [TypeError: b'1' is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369666/typeerror-b1-is-not-json-serializable) as well.

Comment: As I am new to Python, what can be effects of "decode" in this case if you please explain.

Comment: @Kuntal [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) is used to return a string decoded from the given bytes. The problem is that you can't serialize a bytes object with JSON, so you need to transform it in some way. A string representation of the image is what you wanted, right?

Comment: I want to store an image in my Cloudant Database. I think only way to do that is to store the encoded string of the image as json. I am more than happy to try your suggestion .One question, could I face any problem if I try to create the image from this decoded string again ?

Comment: @Kuntal have you tried for yourself to restore the image from the encoding? You should be able to use `base64.base64decode` to recover the image from the decoding. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: so far your solution works as a charm.Thanks a lot. I will try to get it back to image.